# Why the sid i get from parsing the cookie with socket.io and the one from req.session.id using express are different?

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I am in the middle of something really weird with my sessions.

It worked since weeks and just today, when i try to get the session from the `SessionStore` (from `connect-mongo`) the callback return `undefined variables`.

I do send a good sid, it worked this way for weeks, and the session system works since i can access stored variables from `req.session`.

So i was wondering maybe there are 2 different sessions, is there a way to find the sid thought the `req.session` ?

I don't know if it's right but i have req.session.id different from the sid i get

Here is the code:

```
function parseSessionCookie(cookie, sid, secret) {
  var cookies = require('express/node_modules/cookie').parse(cookie)
, parsed = require('express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils').parseSignedCookies(cookies, secret)
;
  return parsed[sid] || null;
}
io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {
    var sid = parseSessionCookie(data.headers.cookie, 'connect.sid', 'secret');
    SessionStore.get(sid, function(err, session) {
       //err and session are undefined!
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
The problem do is that the `sid` i get from `req.session.id` and the one i get from the SessionStore are different !
Since if i call `SessionStrore.get()` with the sid i get from `req.session.id`, everything works fine !

So how is that possible to have 2 different sessions like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i get it !

The thing is i worked locally, using the URL `http://127.0.0.1` in my client code to connect soket.io and `http://localhost` in my browser, so it's create a Cross-origin resource sharing issue.

I Just changed everything fot `http://localhost` and it works fine !